# mutableStateListOf not doing recomposition on replacing some element in the list with targetsdk 33 and kotlin 1.7.20

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, mutablestateof

Recomposition will happen only when you change the list itself. mutableStateListOf can only notify about adding, removing, or replacing some element in the list.

Reference: [Android Jetpack Compose mutableStateListOf not doing Recomposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69718059/android-jetpack-compose-mutablestatelistof-not-doing-recomposition)

Based on the preceding assumption, recomposition should be triggered on a **like()** method call in below code, and it was happening previously. But since I have updated versions in my code, recomposition is not triggering on a like() method call.

I am using below versions in my project and some other library versions I updated:-

```
val compilesdk = 33
val minsdk = 21
val targetsdk = 33
val kotlin = "1.7.20"
val compose_compiler = "1.4.0"
val compose_ui = "1.3.3"
val compose_runtime = "1.3.3"
val compose_foundation = "1.3.1"
val compose_material = "1.3.1"
```

ViewModel

```
val recipes = mutableStateListOf<Recipe>()

fun like(index: Int, likes: ArrayList<String>) {
    recipes[index] = recipes[index].copy(likes = likes)
}
```

Composables

```
SocialNetworkContent(
      viewModel.recipes,...
)

@Composable
fun SocialNetworkContent(
    recipes: List<Recipe>,
    ...
){
..
items(
                count = recipes.size,
                itemContent = {
                    SocialListItem(
                        recipe = recipes[it],
                        it,
                        sharedPreferences,
                        viewModel,
                        onNavigateToRecipeDetailScreen,
                        onNavigateToUserProfileScreen
                    )
                },
            )
..
}
```

Comment: Is `Recipe` a data class, or does it have an `equals` that includes `likes` in its comparison? If not, then there would be no way for the list to detect that anything has been changed.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Recipe is a data class and it has equals implementation that included likes in its comparison `if (likes != other.likes) return false`

Answer (score 0):

when you need to change position state item in `lazyColumn` or `lazyRow`, you need to add `key`

```
LazyColumn {
    items(
        items = messages,
        key = { message ->
            // Return a stable + unique key for the item
            message.id
        }
    ) { message ->
        MessageRow(message)
    }
}
```