# Jetpack Compose - Upping Element & Filtering MutableStateList Does Not Trigger Recomposition

Tags: android-jetpack, compose-recomposition

I'm trying to build a Jetpack Compose View to display a list of items. The ViewModel takes a list of Items as the initial parameter and the user can search by text to filter out the list of items. I'm having issue that the recomposition does not happen when "filteredItems" is reassigned. I have read the threads, [Android Jetpack Compose mutableStateListOf not doing Recomposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69718059/android-jetpack-compose-mutablestatelistof-not-doing-recomposition), and I do understand that MutableStateList triggers recomposition when elements in the list are added/removed/updated.

```
data class MultiSelectItemModel(
    val id: Int,
    var label: String,
    var selected: Boolean
)

@Composable
fun MultiSelectRowView(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    item: MultiSelectItemModel,
    onSelectChange: (item: MultiSelectItemModel) -> Unit
) {
    var selected = item.selected
    val backgroundColor = if (selected) MaterialTheme.colors.secondaryBackground else MaterialTheme.colors.background

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .background(color = backgroundColor)
            .height(30.dp)
            .clickable {
                selected = !selected
                item.selected = !item.selected
                onSelectChange(item)
            },
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = modifier
                .padding(start = 10.dp, end = 10.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text(
                text = item.label,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal
            )
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
            )
            CustomCheckbox(checked = selected) {
                selected = it
                item.selected = it
                onSelectChange(item)
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun CustomCheckbox(
    checked: Boolean,
    selectColor: Color = Color.Green,
    nonSelectColor: Color = Color.Transparent,
    height: Dp = 20.dp,
    width: Dp = 20.dp,
    onCheckedChange: (value: Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    val toggleableState = ToggleableState(checked)
    val checkedState = remember { mutableStateOf(toggleableState === ToggleableState.On) }
    val borderIconColor = Color.White

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(height)
            .width(width)
            .clickable {
                checkedState.value = !checkedState.value
                onCheckedChange(checkedState.value)
            },
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10),
        backgroundColor = if (toggleableState === ToggleableState.On) selectColor else nonSelectColor,
        border = BorderStroke(0.1.dp, borderIconColor)
    ) {
        if (toggleableState === ToggleableState.On) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Check,
                contentDescription = "Checkmark",
                tint = borderIconColor
            )
        }
    }
}

class MultiSelectViewModel(
    items: List<MultiSelectItemModel>,
    selectedIds: List<Int>
) : ViewModel() {
    private var _items = items.toMutableStateList()
    var allItems = _items
    var filteredItems = _items
    var ids = selectedIds.toMutableStateList()
    var searchText = mutableStateOf("")

    init {
        processIds(selectedIds)
    }

    private fun processIds(ids: List<Int>) {
        _items.forEach { it.selected = ids.indexOf(it.id) !== -1 }
    }

    fun filterItems() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            if (searchText.value.isNotEmpty()) {
                val keywords = searchText.value.toUniqueTexts()
                var foundCount: Int

                filteredItems = _items.filter {
                    foundCount = 0

                    keywords.forEach { keyword ->
                        if (it.label.lowercase().contains(keyword)) foundCount++
                    }

                    foundCount === keywords.size
                }.toMutableStateList()
            } else {
                filteredItems = _items
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
private fun ItemList(
    items: List<MultiSelectItemModel>,
    selectedIds: List<Int>,
    vm: MultiSelectViewModel = MultiSelectViewModel(items = items, selectedIds = selectedIds),,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    var selectAllItem by remember { vm.selectAllItem }
    val filteredItems = vm.filteredItems
    val allItems = remember { vm.allItems }
    var searchText = remember { vm.searchText }

    LazyColumn(
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        if (filteredItems.size == allItems.size && searchText.value.isEmpty()) {
            item {
                MultiSelectRowView(
                    item = selectAllItem,
                    onSelectChange = {
                        vm.handleSelectAllItemChanged()
                    }
                )
            }
        }
        items(
            items = filteredItems,
            key = { item -> item.id }
        ) {
            MultiSelectRowView(
                item = it,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(35.dp)
            ) {
                vm.handleSelectChanged()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to use 
var state by mutableStateOf(your list)
        private set
it will trigger changes in Compose Functions

Comment: I tried mutableStateOf(list), in the composable, I changed it to `val filteredItems by vm.filteredItems` but whenever filtering happening in the viewModel and value changes, `filteredItems` in the composable stays the same.

Comment: I'll send you example

Comment: Thanks. I also wanted to know if I should use `remember` in the composable function for `filteredList`. I believe I should not use it because I don't want the composable to keep the state as the viewModel takes care of the current state of the list.