# How to handle updating elements of (nested) lists in UiState

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I am trying to build an over-the-board Go app to help myself learn Jetpack Compose. I have my game logic in a custom class, separate from the the UI, with a 2D array to represent the board:

```
@Stable
@Immutable
data class GameState (
        val boardSize: Int = 19,
        val moveStack: ArrayDeque<Move> = ArrayDeque<Move>(),
        val board: List<List<Location>> = buildList {
                for (row in 0 until boardSize) {
                        add(buildList {
                                for (col in 0 until boardSize) {
                                        add(Location(
                                                coordinate = Pair(row, col),
                                                boardSize = boardSize
                                        ))
                                }
                        })
                }
        }

) {
// methods
}
```

Then I have a UiState which holds the gameState, and anything else that the UI is going to need:

```
data class GoUiState (
    val gameState: GameState = GameState(), // todo construct board according to size settings
    val playerOneScore: Int = 0,
    val playerTwoScore: Int = 0
        )
```

Finally, I have a ViewModel:

```
class GoViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(GoUiState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<GoUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()
    // and so on
```

I have been having problems getting changes in the gameState to be reflected in the UI. From what I have gathered by looking at other questions on this forum, as well as doing my best to read the docs, my understanding is that re-composition is only triggered when the value of the variable that Compose is looking at changes (i.e., the value of the pointer). For this reason, if I just update the list entry corresponding to a particular square, re-composition is not triggered, since the value of the `board` has not changed in the uiState.

The solution that I have reached is to completely rebuild the board array every time I need to update the state of the Board composable for user. For example, in the function which is called when a player makes a move, I have been re-building the entire board like so (this is a method of the GameState class):

```
fun inputMove(
                row: Int,
                col: Int,
                piece: Piece
        ): GameState {
                val newGameState = GameState(
                        boardSize = boardSize,
                        moveStack = moveStack,
                        // rebuild the whole thing so all the pointers change
                        board = buildList {
                                for (row in 0 until boardSize) {
                                        add(buildList {
                                                for (col in 0 until boardSize) {
                                                        add(Location(
                                                                board[row][col].piece,
                                                                board[row][col].coordinate,
                                                                boardSize,
                                                                board[row][col].hasKo
                                                        ))
                                                }
                                        })
                                }
                        }
                )
                // game logic ...
```

This seems very inefficient. I'm triggering the re-composition of every single board location, even though only one of them has changed. Also, I'm guessing my app will have to allocate memory for the new `board` variable, and while I know it's not a practical issue in an app of this scale, it just seems... wrong?

So, my question is: Is there a better way to do this? What I have is a nested `List` in my `UiState`. The composable for each board location only needs to know about the State of the corresponding location in the nested list, so I have written them to take only that information. I have learned that it is good practice to only pass the information that a composable needs to know, but in this case when that information changes the composable does not re-compose because of the way re-composition is triggered. Is there a better way to structure my `UiState` class (keeping in mind that a nested list is a very natural way to represent a game board so I don't really want to change it)? Or, is there a way that I can tell Compose that it needs to recompose *this particular composable* when it is clicked?

I have tried initializing a new `GameState` object inside the `inputMove` function, but this does not seem to work. However, when I reconstruct the entire `board`, updates to the UI work as expected.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think there are special types for collections. For example, you can use [mutableStateListOf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69718585/20898396) to replace a specific item.

Comment: You can use `data.copy` to avoid redoing a computation. `data = data.copy(board = slighltlyModifierBoard)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way but could `board` be `State<List<List<Location>>>` instead of `List<List<Location>>`?

From the Android developers guide on State:

"Caution: Using mutable objects such as ArrayList or mutableListOf() as state in Compose causes your users to see incorrect or stale data in your app. Mutable objects that are not observable, such as ArrayList or a mutable data class, are not observable by Compose and don't trigger a recomposition when they change. **Instead of using non-observable mutable objects, the recommendation is to use an observable data holder such as State<List> and the immutable listOf().**"

[State and Jetpack Compose - Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables)